# Starting and Stopping Rigid Body Simulations

Tags: animation, camera, rigid-body-simulation

Given a rigid body simulation, can i pause it in the middle, move a camera and start it again?

Kind of like a bullet time effect

This is what I want it to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdaXW.jpg (sorry about the quality) 
but with keyframes

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under rigid body tools on the toolshelf there should be a "Bake to keyframes" option. You can run your simulation, and then bake it all to keyframes.

Then in the dopesheet, you can move these keyframes later in time starting from when you want to animate the camera.

E.g.

1. Simulate 20 frames
2. Move keys on frames 11 to 20 to frames 16-25
3. Animate camera between frames 11 and 16