# how to reset dynamic/physic simulation at frame other than 0?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a dynamic (rigid body) simulation, but my animation range is from frame 584 to 716. So i don't start from frame 0. The problem is i can't start the simulation because i have to go to frame 0 for simulation to work. Is there any trick without have to slide/offset all my animation/scene to start from 0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/physics-are-not-simulated-past-a-certain-frame

Answer (score 2):

Look for the settings for the simulation's cache.

There you can set the start and end frames for the simulation. The default values are 1 to 250, but you can change them to fit your needs.

in 2.79:

[image]

in 2.8:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can bake the simulation intop keyrframes and 
 move them in the graph editor or the dope-sheet See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77976/starting-and-stopping-rigid-body-simulations